# Add dynamic HTML with JQuery without hard coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose you have some JavaScript (with JQuery) code that adds some HTML to an existing page, like:

```
var span = "<span>Text</span>";
some_div_element.append(span);
```

Is there any way to do this without having the span hard coded? If I want to add a big portion of code, it just doesn't seem right to have it hard coded in the middle of JavaScript code.

Comment: You could look into some templating languages, such as http://handlebarsjs.com/ Handlebars

Comment: You could store the HTML in a file and load it dynamically.  See:  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy actually with the jquery load function

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includehtml").load("loadme.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includehtml"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

This way you can have your extra html in a different html file, and just load it in with the load function. The html can be as short or long as you would like without bloating your original page. `loadme.html` would need to be stored in the same path on the server in this case.

Comment: How did I not know this!? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) docs, you can pass `.append()` a jQuery element, like this:

```
$("#some_div_element").append( $("span") );
```

With this functionality, you can easily build your `span` element somewhere in your HTML with `display:none` and then get/edit/append it in your Javascript code.

Comment: I didn't know about this. This will be very useful in the future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to insert the html directly than what you can do is create elements using javascript and then apply there properties separately. However, you will have to write a lot of code. Unless you are planning to reuse the elements i think you should stick with inserting the html directly. Its simpler and more efficient.
Here is an example code:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: This would be a good approach yes, and useful for some situations. For my situation the .load() option is better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create re-usable functions then?

```
function getMeSpan(myText) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = myText;
  return span;
};

someOtherDIV.appendChild(getMeSpan('hello'));
someOtherDIV.appendChild(getMeSpan('world!'));
```

Comment: This was not the problem, that problem was having very big code snippets and not having them hard coded. using .load() will work for me. Thank you.